# Regex (Java) - Need help formulating a specific pattern string

Tags: java, regex

I'm pretty bad with regex so hopefully you guys and gals will be able to help me. I have a string called str and I want to ensure that it is of the following form: it is either nothing, or it's a single number (which can be any number of digits), or it's any number of numbers (each number can be any number of digits long as with the single number case) separated by ~ characters.

So for example, if str were either of the following, it would be in the correct form: "", "0", "123", "13~55", "123~4~121", "1~23~43~4".

How exactly would I go about forming a regex pattern string which str would match if it were valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct could also be:

```
^(\d+(~\d)*)*$
```

The difference from this to the previous Joseph Silber answer is that this one doesn't allow a line that finishes with ~ character.

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't be simpler:

```
^(\d+~?)*$
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?3041l

Comment: @Joseph: close, but doesn't prevent things from ending with ~'s. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
^([0-9]+|(([0-9]+~)*[0-9]+))?$
```